# wordpress Meta_query between numbers range (not working)

Tags: meta-query

I have a  meta field called  (sizes_avaliable) for my custom post type , and it looks like this :

sizes_avaliable for post id 1:
15-25-35-45

sizes_avaliable for post id 2:
55-65-75-85

and I have a search input that users can search their particular size in dropdown like this :

```
I need Size between:

11-19 ;

31-39 ;

51-59 ;

81-89 ;
```

So ,, if user searched for size from the drop-down (  11-19 ) .. it will list the post id (1) because it has numbers (15) in the range ,

so I tried this query .

```
$meta_query = array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'sizes_avaliable',
        'value'   => '11-19',
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
);
```

but this doesn't show any results ..

can you help ??

thanks :)

---

**update :**

this is screenshot for my records :
[image]

... so for example.. i need a user when he search 150-200

[image]

it will show the highlighted post ID because it has value 192

thanks. –

Comment: Post meta field values are saved in the database as strings. A query for a meta value of 11-19 will only return results if the meta value in the database is the exact string `11-19`. You would have more success using a taxonomy to store size data because a [taxonomy query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) allows you to query for an array of term IDs.

Answer (score 2):

you can use meta query operators like below query. See docs for meta_query parameters [**here**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)

```
$range = $_GET['range']; // assuming you get the range from query string parameter which 11-19
$range_array = explode('-',$range);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'YOUR-POST-TYPE',
    'meta_query' => array( 
     array(
         'key' => 'sizes_avaliable',
         'value' =>  $range_array,
         'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
         ),
     )
);
```

It would be better if you add screenshot of table containing record of sizes against id. so i will check for it if my answer doesn't work for you.

Comment: Noman thanks for your help ... and this is a screenshot for my records : this is screenshot for my records :[link]https://pasteboard.co/H1PZDbA.png ... so i need a user when he search 150-200 [link]https://pasteboard.co/H1Q2whk.png .. it will show the highlighted post ID because it has value 192 .. di you get it ?? thanks.

Comment: In my case I had to pass each range values in `floatval()` to make it work.